# Cast collection of objects to collection of concrete class

Tags: c#, generic-collections

Consider, that I've the following method:

```
public T Resolve<T>()
{
    var targetType = typeof(T);

    if (targetType.IsGenericType
          && targetType.GetGenerictTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    {
        List<object> collection = this.ResolveCollection(targetType);

        return (T)(object)collection;
    }

    return (T)this.ResolveSingle(targetType);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
IEnumerable<IFoo> coll = myClass.Resolve<IEnumerable<IFoo>>();
```

It is obvious, that sample **will throw exception of invalid cast**, because of covariance - we cannot cast `List<object>` into `IEnumerable<IFoo>` despite `collection` contains implementations of `IFoo` only.
Is there any workaround for that problem when using reflection and non-generic methods?  I don't want to change `Resolve` signature so I don't have generic type of item to use LINQ `Cast`.

Comment: How's `ResolveCollection` defined? Why does it return `List<object>` instead of typed collection?

Comment: `ResolveCollection` is non-generic, so it cannot return collection of concrete classes. Consider, that `ResolveCollection` is external  so cannot modify it or see the source. It takes only `Type` where `Type` is `IEnumerable` and returns `List` with few instances of type of generic argument of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: There is something strange about your `if` condition. Did you mean `targetType.IsGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yeah, sure - I've typed code manually and made mistake, in code there is `IsGenericType` of course.

Comment: `return (T)collection;`: How could a conversion exist from `List<object>` to `T` when `T` has no constraints? ***Edit:*** This is a compile-time error, not a "throw" of a run-time exception.

Comment: It is checked with reflection. I could create multiple Resolve methods like: `ResolveSingle`, `ResolveCollection`, `Resolve..`. But I want to close it inside one method and check constraints with reflection (like it is checked that `T` is `IEnumerable`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen in my real case `ResolveCollection` is casted to object first. Added to sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround:

```
List<object> collection = this.ResolveCollection(targetType);

var itemType = targetType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
var listType =  typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);

var listInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(listType, new object[0]) as IList;
foreach (var instance in collection) 
{
    listInstance.Add(instance);
}

return (T)listInstance;
```

Then, casting works like a chram.

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be ugly. You can also call the Linq method `Enumerable.Cast<>` after "making" it, i.e. filling out the generic argument.

Here is an extension method:

```
public static TIEnumerable ToIEnumerable<TIEnumerable>(this IEnumerable<object> source)
{
  var type = typeof(TIEnumerable);
  if (!type.IsGenericType || type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    throw new ArgumentException("Wrong type arg: " + type, "TIEnumerable");

  var methOpen = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast");
  var methConstructed = methOpen.MakeGenericMethod(type.GenericTypeArguments[0]);

  return (TIEnumerable)methConstructed.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, });
}
```

(You could even extend the non-generic `IEnumerable` since `Cast<>` operates on that.)

Then the body of your `if` (in your question) could be:

```
    List<object> collection = this.ResolveCollection(targetType);

    return collection.ToIEnumerable<T>();
```

If you want eager iteration and returning a `List<>`, that is:

```
    List<object> collection = this.ResolveCollection(targetType);

    return collection.ToIEnumerable<T>()
        .ToList();
```